# how can i turn ' into %27 for this command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

rn im trying to make a command that will create a link for you to a specific site,but there is a problem,there are stuff that have '  in them like "God's will", and if i use ' in my command it wont work because in the link ' is replaced by %27,is there a way so that it will turn ' into %27 automatically in this command?

```
@client.command()
async def mlwiki(ctx, *args):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your Wiki search:", description='**[Results](https://monsterlegends.fandom.com/wiki/{})**'.format('_'.join([arg.capitalize() for arg in args])), color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_footer (text ="Atention!,if you put the terms wrong,the link won't work")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use urllib

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

string = "your url with ' "

print(quote(string))
>>> your%20url%20with%20%27%20
```

It will encode your string to a good url format